# How do I get the byte array of the a gif image without PIL?

Tags: python, gif, lzw

im trying to get a byte array, such as

```
47 49 46 38 39 61 0A 00 0A 00 91 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 21 F9 04 00 00 00 00 00 2C 00 00 00 00 0A 00 0A 00 00 02 16 8C 2D 99 87 2A 1C DC 33 A0 02 75 EC 95 FA A8 DE 60 8C 04 91 4C 01 00 3B
```

from a gif file in python. However, somehow i couldn't download PIL so is there any other way to do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: How about opening the file in binary mode ('rb')? Then all you need to know is the internal structure of a GIF

Answer (score 0):

In order to output the binary content (as 8-bit hexadecimal values) of a GIF (or, indeed, any file) you could do this:

```
GIF = '/Volumes/G-Drive/demo.gif'

with open(GIF, 'rb') as gif:
    print(' '.join(f'{b:02x}' for b in gif.read()))
```

For large files, this could introduce an unacceptable memory overhead. The following variant uses less memory but produces the same result:

```
GIF = '/Volumes/G-Drive/demo.gif'

with open(GIF, 'rb') as gif:
    space = ''
    for b in gif.read():
        print(f'{space}{b:02x}', end='')
        space = ' '
    print()
```